# Passing data from Firebase Database into another ViewController not working and segue wont work consequently

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, segue

I am trying to use data from my Firebase Database to set variables in my destination view controller and I can't really figure out if it is an issue with threading(not using the right queue) or I am not calling the perform segue with identifier the right way.
Here is my prepare for segue function.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    ProfileService.sharedInstance.getPreparedForProfilePage(completionHandler: { (un, sn, pi, pb) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if segue.identifier == SEGUE_TO_PROFILE {
                if segue.destination.isKind(of: ProfileVC.self) {
                    let destination = segue.destination as! ProfileVC
                    destination.userName = un
                    destination.formattedScreenName = sn

                    do {
                        let pi_url = URL(string: pi)
                        let imgData = try Data(contentsOf: pi_url!)
                        let profImg = UIImage(data: imgData)
                        destination.profileImage = profImg
                        }
                    catch {}

                    do {
                        let pb_url = URL(string: pb)
                        let imgData = try Data(contentsOf: pb_url!)
                        let profBanner = UIImage(data: imgData)
                        destination.profileBannerImage = profBanner
                    }
                    catch {}
                    self.shouldSegue = true
                }

            }
        }

    })
}
```

the tuple's values from the completion handler are all strings (the last two image url strings) which is from my singleton class where I do the Firebase query and they work fine after making print statements. but the segue just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You need to do your firebase request before this function is called because most likely this function is ending before your firebase request is completed. You should have a function that downloads from firebase and then calls `performSegue(withIdentifier: String, sender: Any?)` which will pass that downloaded data to the new view controller.

Comment: turns out problem was from me not parsing the data from the Firebase as I should. thanks anyway.